# Which collection class used to map string to string?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

Is there any collection class that maps string to string in Blackberry 4.7 api...If there how to implement it..I found Map class in java api which maps string to string...can anyone know please tell me....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [Hashtable](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Hashtable.html)